# Why there is a app.so file in Flutter Windows build

Tags: flutter

When I build a Windows version of a Flutter app it creates a

```
build\windows\runner\Release\data\app.so 6MB sized file.
```

Obviously it an Linux ELF library yet deleting or renaming the file makes the EXE fail to start.

What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Posted at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104373

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered in Github:

*"Flutter applications that are AOT compiled us a .so on Windows, Linux desktop, and Android. This file contains only your Dart code. Separately, the executable is compiled from the platform specific entry point in the windows directory, along with your plugins and this depends on a dll (flutter engine) which contains the actual engine as well as the support for loading AOT compiled Dart code."*